# Recommended architechture for multiple wordpress installations with a shared database

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to create a several Wordpress websites with a unique relationship between them:
- There will be one main WP site - main.com with several categories for posts.
- There will be several WP sites installed under subdomains: daughter1.main.com , daughter2.main.com
- The daughter sites need to pull posts from several categories (not all of them, and each might pull from different categories) of the main site, but they still need to have independent posts on categories of their own (unique for them).

How would you suggest to approach that?

Please note that the daughter sites will be used as a sub domain of different sites (e.g daughter1.main.com will actually be a subdomain of random.com (somedomain.random.com)). But this can probably be done via simple DNS mapping.

Thanks,

Roy

Comment: The actual domain name layout isn't important, just that they are all on the same machine. Here are the relevant docs for Network/Multisite in WP: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: Thanks. I read this, but it doesn't say whether the features I need are supported by the Multisite feature of Wordpress. It simply explains how to setup the network.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I believe I solved this by myself. Here is how I'm going to approach this:

1. Setup WP 3.0 with Netword/MultiSite configuration
2. Setup the daughter sites as subdomains (part of the network)
3. Add [FeedWordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedwordpress/) plugin to daughter sites
4. Add the RSS feeds of the relevant categories in the FeedWordPress settings
5. Install WordPress MU Domain Mapping on the daughter sites and map the sites properly

I hope others will find this useful.